# Split each bar chart to its x value column

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, charts, telerik

I have a bar chart and I got a little problem in it.. it's grouping all bars to one single x value column .. i need to split each bar to its x value.. take a look at the snap shoot of the problem.. 
[image]

and my code:

```
RadChart1.PlotArea.XAxis.AutoScale = false;
        RadChart1.PlotArea.XAxis.Items.Clear();
        RadChart1.Series.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
         ChartSeries series = new ChartSeries(dt.Rows[i]["day_name"].ToString(), ChartSeriesType.Bar);
           series.Items.Add(new ChartSeriesItem(Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i]["total_timesheet"])));

           ChartAxisItem axisItem = new ChartAxisItem(dt.Rows[i]["doc_date"].ToString());
           RadChart1.PlotArea.XAxis.Items.Add(axisItem);
           RadChart1.Series.Add(series);
        }
```

Comment: difficult to understand your requirement? the bars are not coming at right position?

Comment: Ok look i have stored proc I select as it looks in the grid in the pic day, date, total time sheet.. so i want to make the chart looks something like this set x value to date and series which its on the right of the chart to the day with different colors, all of that is working fine but it seemed like i got something in my for loop that makes all the records or bars to the total time sheet view in the first date only (first x value). so i need to make each bar value to its date time. can u think whats wrong there? I think we'll make another loop on the ChartSeriesItem.